# Using mathematica to understand linear algebra

Tags: plotting

What is the reason why this does not work, as you can see there is three unknown and I want to see the planes. I have looked through the user manual but there is something that I am not realising!

Could someone please take the time to correct this code and explain where I went wrong?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{2 x - y, -x + 2y - z, 0 - 3 y + 4 z}}, {x, -20, 
   20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, Opacity[0.5]}, {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16], Style["y", 16], Style["z", 16]}]
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to plot?

Comment: First, you have error in the API, you wrote `{{2 x - y, -x + 2y - z, 0 - 3 y + 4 z}, {x, -20, 20}}` notice, you included a range specs inside the functions. i.e. you included `{x, -20, 20}` where it does not belong. Second, what is the parameters you are using? The helps shows that max of 2 parameters can be used, `u` and `v`.  Are you sure `ParametricPlot3D` is what you want to use?

Comment: The error with the range is obviously wrong, I basically want to plot a 3D graph where the planes meet. Mostly to use as a visualization, I just do not get how to do it, as 3D plot only take on two variables?

Comment: @Szabolcs I am trying to visualise the intersection with the planes

Comment: @ALEXANDER Could you possibly turn each plane into z=rhs, where rhs is multiples of x, y and a constants? Then you could Plot3D the list of the three right hand sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to visualise the intersection with the planes

```
Remove["Global`*"];
eq1 = 2 x - y == 0;
eq2 = -x + 2 y - z == 0;
eq3 = -3 y + 4 z == 0;
lim = 10;
spec = {{x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, {z, -lim, lim}};
lbl = {"x", "y", "z"};

p1 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq1, Evaluate[Sequence @@ spec], 
   PlotLabel -> "2 x-y", AxesLabel -> lbl, ContourStyle -> Red];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq2, Evaluate[Sequence @@ spec], 
    PlotLabel -> "-x+2y-z", AxesLabel -> lbl, ContourStyle -> Blue];
p3 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eq3, Evaluate[Sequence @@ spec], 
   PlotLabel -> "-3 y+4 z", AxesLabel -> lbl];

Grid[{{p1, p2, p3}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{b, a} = CoefficientArrays[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x, y, z}];
sol = LinearSolve[a, -b] // N (*find point of intersection*)
Show[p1, p2, p3, Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[sol]}], 
   PlotLabel -> "point where surfaces meet)"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice example, +1! However `Sphere` looks better then `Point` in 3D.

Comment: @ybeltukov thanks for the hint. I changed the point to sphere. yes, it looks better.

Comment: What would be a good way to plot the line of intersection if that were the case?